# How can I install word font programmatically?

Tags: vba, fonts, ms-word

I'm creating a word template for some users, and I need to use "MT Extra" font, which I know is common for all word versions, but I need to be sure that it's installed because at the time of word installation user may choose not to install any font!

So can I add a VBA piece of code to install this font on user's machine, whatever the settings of machine are ?? (32/64 bit or whatever).

Comment: Have you tried embedding the font in the template? In Word, when saving, go to Save Options. Under 'Preserve fidelity when sharing this document', tick 'Embed fonts in the file' (also un-tick 'Embed only the characters used in the document' and 'Do not embed common system fonts').

Comment: Yes it helps!
But it added around 4 MB to my document :S

Comment: Ah, OK, it's embedding all of the other fonts you use. You could try ticking the 'Do not embed common system fonts' checkbox to see if that reduces the size. Only problem is, I'm not sure whether MT Extra is considered a common system font or not :-/

Comment: It reduces the size, it adds around 2 MB instead of 4 MB.
As I found, MT Extra is common for windows versions, but I can change it to another weird font :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so easy...

Have a look here: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/728740/How-can-I-install-word-font-programmatically-using